Why are images not displayed using Angular and Visual Studio Code?
I started learning Angular with a tutorial and I was told to put this into a header component:
(I even found a hint to put the path in additional single quotes inside the double quotes, which doesn't work.)
The image does exist in the assets folder.
Furthermore, I was told to replace the whole content of app.component.html with this code:
<app-header/>

After building and starting, I invoke http://localhost:4200 and the page appears but the image could not be found.
The assets are not displayed into the dist folder? Why not?
It doesn't matter if I use <img src="assets/..."/> or <img src="/assets/..."/> (with a leading slash).

The sourceode of the page displayed in Google Chrome:
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head>
  <script type="module" src="/@vite/client"></script>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>MyFirstProject</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"><style ng-app-id="ng">

header[_ngcontent-ng-c4022922458] {
  background-color: lightgray;
  box-shadow: 8px 8px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
/*# sourceMappingURL=header.component.css.map */</style></head>
<body><!--nghm-->
  <app-root _nghost-ng-c3361530648="" ng-version="18.0.3" ngh="0" ng-server-context="ssr"><app-header _ngcontent-ng-c3361530648="" _nghost-ng-c4022922458="" ngh="0"><header _ngcontent-ng-c4022922458=""><img _ngcontent-ng-c4022922458="" src="/assets/Logoduitbluesmall.jpg" alt="bla"></header></app-header><br _ngcontent-ng-c3361530648="">
xxx <img _ngcontent-ng-c3361530648="" src="/assets/Logoduitbluesmall.jpg" alt="uff"><br _ngcontent-ng-c3361530648="">
yyy <img _ngcontent-ng-c3361530648="" src="/assets/Logoduitbluesmall.jpg" alt="zack"></app-root>
<script src="polyfills.js" type="module"></script><script src="main.js" type="module"></script>

<script id="ng-state" type="application/json">{"__nghData__":[{}]}</script></body></html>


VisualStudoi Code:
Version: 1.91.0 (user setup)
Commit: ea1445cc7016315d0f5728f8e8b12a45dc0a7286
Date: 2024-07-01T18:52:22.949Z
Electron: 29.4.0
ElectronBuildId: 9728852
Chromium: 122.0.6261.156
Node.js: 20.9.0
V8: 12.2.281.27-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19045
I started Visual Studio Code on a Windows 10 PC within a WSL console.

I found out that there is a file called angular.json in the project's root which contains a section like this:
          "assets": [
          {
            "glob": "**/*",
            "input": "public"
          }
        ],

by default after creating a new project.
After changing public to /src/assets/ and <img src="Logoduitbluesmall.jpg"/> in header.component.html the image gets displayed.
